# Is my proof/thought regarding metric spaces and mappings correct?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let  $(X,d)$ be a metric space  $A,B \subset X$ and $A\cap B = \varnothing$ and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb R $ continuously. Show $0 \le f \le 1$ and $f^{-1}(0)=A$ and $f^{-1}(1)=B$.
$$f(x)= \frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$$

I have already showed that $0 \le f \le 1$  now I wanted to show the last two statements.

My attempt was the following (which I think is not right):
Because $f$ is continuous, than $f^{-1}$ is the bijective map of $f$.
We know that $A\cap B = \varnothing$ so $f(A\cap B) =f(A)\cap (B)= 0 \cap 1= 
\varnothing$

We know that a singleton is always closed, so I'm done.

But I think that this is not enough or wrong because I have to show four set inclusions, am I right ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement of what you say you want to prove is simply nonsense - you want to prove something about $f$ without assuming anything about $f$. What did the problem actually ask? Try again, without leaving out the little words you left out...

Comment: @David :Sorry, changed $f$ and $h$.

Comment: You probably want to show that *there exists $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $0\le f(x)\le1$, $f^{-1}(0)=A$ and $f^{-1}(1)=B$*.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. For example take $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in X$. Then $f$ meets your conditions and $f^{-1}(0)=X$ and $f^{-1}(1)=\emptyset$.

Comment: Do you mean "Let A,B⊂X b closed and disjoint subsets of  a metric space X and h: X→R continuously and 0≤h≤1. Show $h^{−1}(0)=A$ and $h^{-1}(1)= B"  or "Let A,B⊂X b closed and disjoint subsets of  a metric space X and h: X→R continuously and 0≤h≤1. Show $f^{−1}(0)=A$ and $f^{-1}(1)= B"?

Comment: YOu missed one $h$. But regardless, the statement is still obviously false, although not quite as nonsensical as the original. The hypotheses obviously cannot imply the conclusion - there's no connection between $A,B$ and $f$ given. _Once again_: Tell us what the problem __really_ asked! Not your version.

Comment: @egreg Well obviously that's what he's supposed to show. Imo this sort of hint is a bad thing - all the OP had to do is_read_ the original problem again, much more carefully. Learning to do that is an important skill (and if he's not willing to put _that_ much effort into the problem he really doesn't have an answer coming...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I understand, but you should also consider the language barrier.

Comment: @egreg If you say so - II see no evidence of any problem with English here. (And if there were a language barrier I'd still say that learning not to skip little details like the words "there exists" is kind of important.) What I do see is multiple edits, without _yet_ going back and re-reading the problem (and also curiously ignoring your reading the original problem to him...)

Comment: @all: I edited the question and hope that it's now clear what I meant. I'm really sure that it's written "to show" and not "there exists"

Comment: You know you still have not given a correct _statement_ of the problem. People have even _told_ you what the problem must really be asking, but you keep reposting incorrect versions. All you have to do is _read_ the original problem and telll us what it says. But _without_ leaving out any of those little words...

Comment: _Is_ that formula for $f$ also part of the problem statement? (i) If yes: Then you still have not stated the problem correctly. (ii) If no, and if it really says "show" then the problem is obviously wrong. I don't get this bit about how you're "quite sure" what it says. Why not just read it, and _tell_ us **exactly** what it says?

Comment: @David: Yes, it's the formula. I just want to show/proof that $A=f^{-1}(1)$

Comment: Look. One reason learning math is a good thing is it forces you to make sense. What you've written still makes no sense. You _could_ post a version that makes sense by looking back at the original question. See, you evidently think that the differences between the way the problem is stated and what you've written don't matter. But they do - learning exactly why what you've been writing is not the same as what the problems asks would be much more useful than this detail about metric spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space; let $A$ and $B$ be closed subsets of $X$ such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Define the function $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ by
>   $$
> f(x)=\frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}
> $$
>   and prove
>
> (a) $f$ is continuous
>   (b) for all $x\in X$, $0\le f(x)\le 1$
>   (c) $f^{-1}(0)=A$ and $f^{-1}(1)=B$

Suggested steps:

1. If $C\subseteq X$, the function $x\mapsto d(x,C)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in C\}$ is continuous (prove it)
2. If $A\subseteq X$ is closed, then $d(x,A)=0$ if and only if $x\in A$ (prove it)
3. Since $A\cap B=\emptyset$, we have from 2 that $d(x,A)+d(x,B)>0$ for all $x\in X$ (why?)
4. Applying 3, the function $f$ is well defined
5. Applying 1, the function $f$ is continuous (prove it)
6. Prove (b)
7. If $f(x)=0$, then…
8. If $x\in A$, then…
9. If $f(x)=1$, then…
10. If $x\in B$, then…

---

**Notes.**

$f$ need not be bijective; the notation $f^{-1}(0)$ should be interpreted as
$$
f^{-1}(0)=\{x\in X:f(x)=0\}
$$
and similarly for $f^{-1}(1)$.

You're wrong in stating that $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$; only $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$ can be proved in general. Moreover, it's completely irrelevant for the problem at hand.

You may already know steps from 1 to 5, if you have already discussed $d(x,C)$.